# Group operation and a doubly stochastic matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $p(i)$ is the probability of state $i$ with $p(i)>0$ and $p_{ij}=p(j.i^{-1})$ are transition probabilities where product and inverse refer to group operations, how can I show that the transition probability matrix is doubly stochastic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that to show that the matrix $P$, with coordinates $p_{ij}$, is doubly stochastic, it is enough to show that the values of each rows and each column sum to $1$.

For this, observe that $\sum\limits_i p(i) = 1$.

Now consider the $j'$th column,
the sum of of elements in this column is given by 
$$\sum\limits_i p_{ij} = \sum\limits_i p(j \cdot i^{-1}) = \sum\limits_{j^{-1}\cdot i^{-1}|i \in G} p(i) = 1,$$
where the second equality is just a change of variables.

The same logic also holds for the sum of rows, which gives the desired result.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second equality. Could you please break it down or explain for me? Should the range of the sum be $j^{-1}\cdot i|i \in G$? How does it sum to 1? I think I'm quite naive!

Comment: The main idea is that to go over all elements in the group of the type $j \cdot i^{-1}$ (where $j$ is fixed and $i$ is every possible element in $G$), is exactly like simply going over all elements in the group.                                                               To see this, for $g \in G$, just take $i = g^{-1} \cdot j$, so that $j\cdot i^{-1} = g$.